# jquery ajax slide function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a snip of code that inst working the way it is supposed to.

```
function showContent(pos,direction){
$("#area").hide("slide", { direction: direction=="left"?"right":"left"}, 2000);
$("#area").load("flow_forms.jsp #area" + pos);
$("#area").show("slide", { direction: direction }, 500);
}

$('#next').click(function(){
    if(question_pos==0){
        question_pos+=1;
        showContent(question_pos,"right");
        return true;
```

The area is supposed to slide to the left, load off-screen, then slide in from the right with the loaded area contents.

Basically the problem I am having is that the .load is occurring before the .hide. So what I have is an area that loads as it slides to the left, then brings in the already loaded area in from the right. My boss suggested a callback function, but I don't even know what that is...

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to stop the .load until after the .hide is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of **callback functions** - these are run once the current function has finished executing, like so:

```
function showContent(pos,direction){
    $("#area").hide("slide", { direction: direction=="left"?"right":"left"}, 2000,      
        function(){
            $("#area").load("flow_forms.jsp #area" + pos, function(){
                $("#area").show("slide", { direction: direction }, 500);
            }); // Load callback 
        } // Hide callback            
    );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do the second part, the second function is undefined. Im not sure how to use callbacks, so maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: Basically now the slide left works, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Ah, turns out I missed a closing brace, I've updated the code. Check out [the hide() docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for more info on callbacks - the second argument listed as _complete_ on there.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `.load` wait until the first animation has completed, either by using a completion callback, or by taking a "promise" on the element's animation queue:

```
$("#area").hide(...).promise().done(function() {
    $("#area").load(..., function() {
        $(this).show(...);
    });
});
```

There's actually a better option, though, which would allow you to *start* the `.load` while the animation is ongoing - this would be more responsive:

```
var $tmp = $('div');

var loaded = $.Deferred(function() {
    $tmp.load(...);  // load into an off-screen div
    this.resolve();
});

var hidden = $('#area').hide(...).promise();

$.when(loaded, hidden).done(function() {
    // move #tmp contents to #area and show it
    $('#area').empty().append($tmp).show();
});
```

The `$.when()` requires that both the AJAX load and the animation have completed, whilst allowing them both to progress at the same time.

Comment: @user2089255 I've updated this - the first answer was based on the `.show()` instead of the `.hide()` - I was confused by you using the same element both for the slide-out and the following slide-in.